# onclick event on JSF tag

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2

How to bind JavaScript `onclick` event to JSF-tag? 
Here's my JSF tag:

```
<h:commandLink value="Edit" action="#{adminBean.edit}">
<f:param value="#{user.login}" name="login"/>
</h:commandLink>
```

I've managed to bind click-event on a JSP-tag
JavaScript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function deleteUser(link)
{
    if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
        window.location = link;
    }

    else {

    }

}
</script>
```

Here's my link example in JSP-tag.

```
out.println("<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"deleteUser('deleteUser.htm?userLogin="+user.getLogin()+"');\">Delete</a>");
```

How can I bind the same on-click function to given above JSF-tag ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `onclick` attribute in the `<h:commandLink>` tag component:

JSF code

```
<h:commandLink value="Edit" action="#{adminBean.edit}"
    onclick="if (!deleteUser()) return false;">
    <f:param value="#{user.login}" name="login"/>
</h:commandLink>
```

And change your script to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function deleteUser(link) {
        return confirm("Are you sure?");
    }
</script>
```

By the way, I think you have confused the terms *edit* and *delete*, but that's outside the question scope.